# Scale badge requirements according to team size

Tags: feature-request, badges, stack-overflow-for-teams

*For the sake of clarity: This question is about **SO for Teams only**.*

---

For anyone in a small team (i.e. < 100 users) it is actually impossible to gain certain badges, such as [*Great Answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) which requires:

> Answer score of 100 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

In such a small team, unless it grows significantly and/or has a huge fluctuation, there just wouldn't *ever* (in a reasonable sense of that word) be enough people to upvote a single question so many times.

I suggest that the team administrator could set a scale for gaining such badges appropriately to team size. Otherwise, the gamification factor of Stack Overflow for Teams wouldn't work that great for small teams.

The administrator should also have the capability to raise the bar (without affecting badges already assigned) in the future, by adjusting the scale. Alternatively, the system could manage the scale automatically. However, that should be done in a predictable manner, so that the bar isn't being "constantly raised on the go" in order to prevent user frustration.

Comment: How would you determine the scaling? How many users would be needed before a score of 100 is needed for the badge? Also it should be remembered there are sites out there where getting some badges can be near impossible due to the type and amount of traffic from users.

Comment: @JoeW I don't have an answer to *how* to determine the scaling. However, I do see this as a problem. If Teams are to be successful among small teams either, the reputation-based and badge-based gamification should work for them as well.

Comment: Perhaps a more viable solution would be to simply hide badges that are not possible based on the team's size, rather than trying to squish requirements for a family of three badges to scale them to possibility? The particular badge family has three badges of increasing difficulty, and scaling them to something like 3, 5, 10 for bronze, silver, and gold makes the badge kind of pointless and not very special.

Comment: Building on what @animuson said, a team might also want to hide badges that push features that the team discourages using. For instance, a team that really cracks down on comments being used to answer might not want a pundit badge.

Comment: @NickA I didn't say it should be linear.

Comment: @OndrejTucny I'm aware, I was just trying to make a joke... I'll retract my comment which sounded far more amusing in my head than on paper :(.